# Undefined index username in chat functionality

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I am implementing chat functionality in my website. I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: username

So in my chatbox instead of username it displays undefined.

I already include chat.js and jquery.js file.

This is my `Chat.php` file:

```
<?php
define ('DBPATH','localhost');
define ('DBUSER','root');
define ('DBPASS','');
define ('DBNAME','abc');

session_start();
global $dbh;
$dbh = @mysql_connect(DBPATH,DBUSER,DBPASS);
@mysql_select_db(DBNAME,$dbh);

if ($_GET['action'] == "chatheartbeat") { chatHeartbeat(); } 
if ($_GET['action'] == "sendchat") { sendChat(); } 
if ($_GET['action'] == "closechat") { closeChat(); } 
if ($_GET['action'] == "startchatsession") { startChatSession(); } 

if (!isset($_SESSION['chatHistory'])) {
    $_SESSION['chatHistory'] = array(); 
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'])) {
    $_SESSION['openChatBoxes'] = array();   
}

function chatHeartbeat() {

    $sql = "select * from chat where (chat.to = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."' AND recd = 0) order by id ASC";
    $query = @mysql_query($sql);
    $items = '';

    $chatBoxes = array();

    while ($chat = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        if (!isset($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'][$chat['from']]) && isset($_SESSION['chatHistory'][$chat['from']])) {
            $items = $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$chat['from']];
        }

        $chat['message'] = sanitize($chat['message']);

        $items .= <<<EOD
                       {
            "s": "0",
            "f": "{$chat['from']}",
            "m": "{$chat['message']}"
       },
EOD;

    if (!isset($_SESSION['chatHistory'][$chat['from']])) {
        $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$chat['from']] = '';
    }

    $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$chat['from']] .= <<<EOD
                           {
            "s": "0",
            "f": "{$chat['from']}",
            "m": "{$chat['message']}"
       },
EOD;

        unset($_SESSION['tsChatBoxes'][$chat['from']]);
        $_SESSION['openChatBoxes'][$chat['from']] = $chat['sent'];
    }

    if (!empty($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'] as $chatbox => $time) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['tsChatBoxes'][$chatbox])) {
            $now = time()-strtotime($time);
            $time = date('g:iA M dS', strtotime($time));

            $message = "Sent at $time";
            if ($now > 180) {
                $items .= <<<EOD
{
"s": "2",
"f": "$chatbox",
"m": "{$message}"
},
EOD;

    if (!isset($_SESSION['chatHistory'][$chatbox])) {
        $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$chatbox] = '';
    }

    $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$chatbox] .= <<<EOD
        {
"s": "2",
"f": "$chatbox",
"m": "{$message}"
},
EOD;
            $_SESSION['tsChatBoxes'][$chatbox] = 1;
        }
        }
    }
}

    $sql = "update chat set recd = 1 where chat.to = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."' and recd = 0";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($items != '') {
        $items = substr($items, 0, -1);
    }
header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{
        "items": [
            <?php echo $items;?>
        ]
}
<?php
            exit(0);
}

function chatBoxSession($chatbox) {

    $items = '';

    if (isset($_SESSION['chatHistory'][$chatbox])) {
        $items = $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$chatbox];
    }

    return $items;
}

function startChatSession() {
    $items = '';
    if (!empty($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'] as $chatbox => $void) {
            $items .= chatBoxSession($chatbox);
        }
    }


    if ($items != '') {
        $items = substr($items, 0, -1);
    }

header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{
        "username": "<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>",
        "items": [
            <?php echo $items;?>
        ]
}
<?php
    exit(0);
}

function sendChat() {
    $from = $_SESSION['username'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $_SESSION['openChatBoxes'][$_POST['to']] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

    $messagesan = sanitize($message);

    if (!isset($_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']])) {
        $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']] = '';
    }

    $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']] .= <<<EOD
                       {
            "s": "1",
            "f": "{$to}",
            "m": "{$messagesan}"
       },
EOD;


    unset($_SESSION['tsChatBoxes'][$_POST['to']]);

    $sql = "insert into chat (chat.from,chat.to,message,sent) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($from)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($to)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($message)."',NOW())";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "1";
    exit(0);
}

function closeChat() {

    unset($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'][$_POST['chatbox']]);
    exit(0);
}

function sanitize($text) {
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
    $text = str_replace("\n\r","\n",$text);
    $text = str_replace("\r\n","\n",$text);
    $text = str_replace("\n","<br>",$text);
    return $text;
}
?>
```

When startChatSession method call at that times I get this error.

Comment: Are you using codeigniter? Also why don't you set your database information using application/config/database.php and then autoload the library.

Comment: Yes I m using codeigniter. I tried that also but according tutorial I do this way.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you never set any value to $_SESSION['username'].
This is why PHP complains, that the index "username" is not existing in $_SESSION.

Comment: I already set username value in another page and In firefox and chrome it will give the line like:- "username":"<br />" Here It give error of "SyntaxError:JSON parse:bad control character in string literal take at line 2 column 22"

Comment: then it's maybe a session issue. Is there your session id in the url or did php set a cookie with the session id? otherwise session_start() can't know which session to reactivate and just starts a new one which is empty. that would lead to the notice you're getting.

Comment: no session id in url and when i run page sesssion value its get. and also define the function of setcookie ,getcookie and clearcookie and from this page if i remove session_start than it gives the error of _SESSION undefine.

Comment: what if you put behind session_start(); an echo session_id();? Dies every page print the same session id or is it changing form page to page?

Comment: When I echo session_id in another page it give diffrent id and when I echo session_id on chat.php I mean this page Gives diffrent id.

Comment: and one more thing this code which show here this is in core php and another page are in codeigniter.

Comment: when you get different ids on different pages, your session is not configured properly. Check your php.ini if the setting is "session.use_cookies = 1" or not? if it is = 1, then check if your browser blocks sessions. You can also see in the php.ini the session.name (default is PHPSESSID). Then you can go to your browser settings and check if you can find this cookie. One of the above mentioned things should be wrong I think. Fix them and your session should work again.